# In-App Right way

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I´d like to know how is the right way to implement In-App purchases. I mean, is it needed to think about it before to begin coding?.
If I have a full version of my app already implemented (not submitted to App Store yet), and I want to add In-App purchases to enable some features already implemented, can I do it? Or is it needed to implement In-App from the begining,before start coding?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is very general, but yes you can implement in-app purchases even if your app is almost ready.

Comment: Thank you so much. Imagine I finish my App with all features, and now I want to "disable" some of these features and enable them only by In-App purchase. Is that possible? What I want to do is to develop my full App and then add In-App. I hope you understand better.